# How to convert nlohmann binary to uint8_t vector?

Tags: c++, json, msgpack, nlohmann-json

I get a msgpack object, wrapping an array with `uint8_t` values from an API and load it to the nlohmann/json library with `json::from_msgpack`, when I print the json document I get this:

```json
{
  "raw_data": {
    "bytes": [4, 3, 2, 0, 0, 116, 68],
    "subtype": null
  }
}
```

From the [documentation](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/binary_t/) I read that the default values for the BinaryType is `std::vector<std::uint8_t>`. But either way I try it, I get run-time errors like:

```cpp
std::vector<uint8_t> unpack(std::vector<uint8_t> msg){
    json response_json = json::from_msgpack(msg);
    return response_json["raw_data"];
}
```

```
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::detail::type_error'
>  what():  [json.exception.type_error.302] type must be array, but is binary
> Canceled
```

or

```cpp
std::vector<uint8_t> unpack(std::vector<uint8_t> msg){
    json response_json = json::from_msgpack(msg);
    return response_json["raw_data"]["bytes"];
}
```

```
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::detail::type_error'
> what():  [json.exception.type_error.305] cannot use operator[] with a string argument with binary
> Canceled
```

I also tried calling the `set_subtype` - since it is hinted, that the subtype of the binary is not set - but got the same error messages.

Copying the elements in an new vector would be an easy workaround, but I fell so close to accessing the existing vector, that this fells a little wrong. If anyone can give me a hint I would be very grateful :)

Comment: The library is not sure if you are requesting a list or binary data. `response_json["raw_data"].get_binary()` should get you out of that jam.

Comment: @Frank the binary representation could be 4bytes per value. I guess the target was getting a single byte per value.